# FullCalendar Title with Capital letters

Tags: view, fullcalendar

I would like to know how to put capital to the view title, as for instance, I get this:
septiembre / 2015
23 / septiembre / 2015

My view config for the title is:

```
    views: {
        month: { 
            titleFormat: 'MMMM YYYY'
        },
        day: { 
            titleFormat: 'DD / MMMM / YYYY'
        }
    },
```

Hope there is a solution ! :D Cheers !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can edit your CSS and add the following:

```
.fc-toolbar {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

It will set the title text of the calendar in capital letters.

Comment: Thankx Slyvain !. I made something tedious... I edit the JS where it takes the values according to the chosen language and I modified it... But I will use your solution as there is something I can modify... jeje... Thankx again...

Comment: .fc-toolbar .fc-center {
      display: inline-block; 
      text-transform: capitalize
    }
If you want to make just the center text (aka title) with first capital letter only.